# What is the best translation of "Немудрено, что"?

Tags: перевод

I came across a saying on the television, which is "Немудрено, что их лишили свободы, ведь они торговали наркотиками!". How could this phrase be translated, in this case?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"Немудрено" could be literally translated as "Don't need (to be) a wise man to understand this". In your particular case, the translation could be

```
"This is not a surprise that they got jailed, for they were drug dealers."
```